# Get first value of column in dataframe in pandas with offset indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with offset indices and I'd like to access the first value of interested column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0,1,2], "b":[3,4,5]}, index=[5,6,7])
In [20]: df
Out[20]:
   a  b
5  0  3
6  1  4
7  2  5
```

None of the .ix, .loc [methods of pandas dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) didn't help (or I used them inappropriate):

```
In [24]: df.ix[0,"a"]
KeyError: 0

In [27]: df["a"][0]
KeyError: 0
```

I could do it with [reset_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) method but I'd like to keep original dataframe
I found solution but I think it's not the best:

```
In [29]: df["a"].values[0]
Out[29]: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `iloc[0]` to access the first elements:

```
In [193]:
print(df['a'].iloc[0])
print(df['b'].iloc[0])

0
3
```

or `head`:

```
In [194]:
df.head(1)

Out[194]:
   a  b
5  0  3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ...
`[df.loc[currentIndex,'a'] for currentIndex in list(df.index)]`

to just get first element for column a try this

```
df.loc[list(df.index)[0],'a']
```

Comment: You could access firt value of `df.index` without converting it to list: `df.index[0]`